# Problem with displaying the following embeded code in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, widget, tradingview-api

I want to display the following widget from trading wiew

```
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_56bdd"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/?exchange=BITSTAMP" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">BTCUSD Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "width": 1080,
  "height": 720,
  "symbol": "BITSTAMP:BTCUSD",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "light",
  "style": "2",
  "locale": "in",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "hide_top_toolbar": true,
  "withdateranges": true,
  "save_image": false,
  "details": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_56bdd"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
```

if i copy paste this in the html it works fine. But I want to change the parameter "symbol" as per the user's choice so i am trying to display the code through JavaScript, so i am using the follwing code in JS

```
var widgetHtml = '<div class="tradingview-widget-container"> <div id="tradingview_56bdd"></div> <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/?exchange=BITSTAMP" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">BTCUSD Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> new TradingView.widget( { "width": 1080, "height": 720, "symbol": "BITSTAMP:BTCUSD", "interval": "D", "timezone": "Etc/UTC", "theme": "light", "style": "2", "locale": "in", "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6", "enable_publishing": false, "hide_top_toolbar": true, "withdateranges": true, "save_image": false, "details": true, "container_id": "tradingview_56bdd" }); </script> </div>';
document.getElementById("tradingview-widget").innerHTML = widgetHtml;
```

Now instead of the wodget i am getting a link which redicts me to the site, no widget is being displayed.

Is there a better way to display the widget? How can i display the widget through JS?

Sorry for the silly question, i am a beginner and this is my first JS project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

silly question solution i got is as follow

add foll in JS

```
new TradingView.widget(
  { 
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "light",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "in",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_5a5e5"
  }
 );
```

and add following script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
```